# How to parse json array with many nesting with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

Right now my json looks easy and there is one object. suppose there would be many object in json then how could i parse it.

Now my json looks like

```
    var jsonText = @"{
        ""some_number"": 108.541, 
        ""date_time"": ""2011-04-13T15:34:09Z"", 
        ""serial_number"": ""SN1234"",
        ""more_data"": {
            ""field1"": 1.0,
            ""field2"": ""hello""
        }
    }";
```

i am parsing it this way

```
    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var dict = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonText);

    Console.WriteLine(dict["some_number"]); 
    Console.WriteLine(dict["more_data"]["field2"]);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

when there will be nested object in each ordinal of json array then how could i parse with `JavaScriptSerializer`?

Suppose my json look bit complicated like below then how could i parse it by **JavaScriptSerializer**.

```
    var jsonText = @"data[
    {
        ""some_number"": 108.541, 
        ""date_time"": ""2011-04-13T15:34:09Z"", 
        ""serial_number"": ""SN1234"",
        ""more_data"": {
            ""field1"": 1.0,
            ""field2"": ""hello""
        },
        ""Hobbies"" : [""game1"",""game2"",""game3""]
    },
    {
        ""some_number"": 200.541, 
        ""date_time"": ""2012-04-11T15:34:09Z"", 
        ""serial_number"": ""SN3333"",
        ""more_data"": {
            ""field1"": 2.0,
            ""field2"": ""hello1""
        },
        ""Hobbies"" : [""game4"",""game5"",""game6""]
    }]";

    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var dict = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonText);

    Console.WriteLine(dict["some_number"]); 
    Console.WriteLine(dict["more_data"]["field2"]);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

please tell me how could i parse the above json with JavaScriptSerializer. Thanks

### EDIT

Change the json as per your guidance. now tell me does it look right?

```
    var jsonText = @"{ ""data""[
    {
        ""some_number"": 108.541, 
        ""date_time"": ""2011-04-13T15:34:09Z"", 
        ""serial_number"": ""SN1234"",
        ""more_data"": {
            ""field1"": 1.0,
            ""field2"": ""hello""
        },
        ""Hobbies"" : [""game1"",""game2"",""game3""]
    },
    {
        ""some_number"": 200.541, 
        ""date_time"": ""2012-04-11T15:34:09Z"", 
        ""serial_number"": ""SN3333"",
        ""more_data"": {
            ""field1"": 2.0,
            ""field2"": ""hello1""
        },
        ""Hobbies"" : [""game4"",""game5"",""game6""]
    }]}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsonText is not a valid json. You probably need something like:

```
var jsonText = @"{
                  ""data"":[
                      {......
```

make your json valid and the JavaScriptSerializer will work.

**Edit**

If I am guessing right,, your object needs to be

```
var jsonText = @"{""data"":[
{
    ""some_number"": 108.541, 
    ""date_time"": ""2011-04-13T15:34:09Z"", 
    ""serial_number"": ""SN1234"",
    ""more_data"": {
        ""field1"": 1.0,
        ""field2"": ""hello""
    },
    ""Hobbies"" : [""game1"",""game2"",""game3""]
},
{
    ""some_number"": 200.541, 
    ""date_time"": ""2012-04-11T15:34:09Z"", 
    ""serial_number"": ""SN3333"",
    ""more_data"": {
        ""field1"": 2.0,
        ""field2"": ""hello1""
    },
    ""Hobbies"" : [""game4"",""game5"",""game6""]
}]}";
```

so now you can access your object like...

```
dict["data"]  //which is your array containing your two objects
dict["data"][0]["some_number"] //eg first object property
dict["data"][1]["more_data"]["field2"] //second object property...
```

use your watch panel to debug your object.. You should create a model to cast your object into your models. Having unknown models should be avoided unless needed.

Comment: if possible give me bit of code to read some from json array with JavaScriptSerializer. thanks

Comment: see my edit. change the json as per your guidance. now tell me does it look right?

Answer (score 0):

I sort the problem. @itdoesntwork hint really help me to fix the json error.
Here i am sharing my code to show how i did it.

Please add reference of `System.Web.Extensions` and add this namespace using `System.Web.Script.Serialization;` at top

```
    var jsonText = @"{ ""data"":[
    {
        ""some_number"": 108.541, 
        ""date_time"": ""2011-04-13T15:34:09Z"", 
        ""serial_number"": ""SN1234"",
        ""more_data"": {
            ""field1"": 1.0,
            ""field2"": ""hello""
        },
        ""Hobbies"" : [""game1"",""game2"",""game3""]
    },
    {
        ""some_number"": 200.541, 
        ""date_time"": ""2012-04-11T15:34:09Z"", 
        ""serial_number"": ""SN3333"",
        ""more_data"": {
            ""field1"": 2.0,
            ""field2"": ""hello1""
        },
        ""Hobbies"" : [""game4"",""game5"",""game6""]
    }]}";

    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var dict = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonText);

    Console.WriteLine(dict["data"][0]["some_number"]);
    Console.WriteLine(dict["data"][0]["more_data"]["field2"]);

    Console.WriteLine(dict["data"][1]["some_number"]);
    Console.WriteLine(dict["data"][1]["more_data"]["field2"]);
    Console.WriteLine(dict["data"][1]["Hobbies"][1]);

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: you outran me :P

Comment: but i insist.. use models.. avoid using unknown objects.. if your project goes big, many people work on it, or you see your code after months,, unknown objects will be a mess.